# Enabling the `onClick` method in a custom FrameLayout view

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-databinding, android-jetpack

I'm not able to get a `onClick` method to work with a custom FrameLayout view.

When I refactor a default `Button` view into a custom `ProgressButton` view containing a `Button`, the `onClick` method doesn't get called.

Custom `ProgressButton` view class:

```
class ProgressButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes){

    private var button: Button

    init {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_progress_button, this, true)
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.button)
        context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.ProgressButton,
            0, 0
        ).apply {
            try {
                if (hasValue(R.styleable.ProgressButton_buttonText)) {
                    button.text = getString(R.styleable.ProgressButton_buttonText)
                }
                if (hasValue(R.styleable.ProgressButton_buttonBackground)) {
                    button.background = getDrawable(R.styleable.ProgressButton_buttonBackground)
                }
            } finally {
                recycle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ProgressButton` XML Layout file: `res/layout/view_progress_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

Usage of `ProgressButton` view with `android:onClick`:

```
<com.example.ui.common.ProgressButton
        android:id="@+id/progress_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onProgressButtonClick()}"
        app:buttonText="@string/test"
        app:buttonBackground="@drawable/selectable_button_blue"
/>
```

What's the best way to pass a click listener to a custom view using Android databinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have `dataBinding.enabled true` defined in your build.gradle. If not, check [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start) out.

It doesn't look like your layout is currently a databinding layout. First you'd want to convert `view_progress_button.xml` to a databinding layout like the following:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.your.package.YourViewModelClass" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.ui.common.ProgressButton
        android:id="@+id/progress_btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onProgressButtonClick()}"
        app:buttonText="@string/test"
        app:buttonBackground="@drawable/selectable_button_blue"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

There should be an option in Android Studio that lets you auto-convert your layout. Do this by hitting alt + enter (Windows) or option + enter (OSX) on the root ViewGroup in your layout. In this case you'd want to hit that combination on your FrameLayout.

In your `ProgressButton` class, you'd want to do something like this:

```
val binding: ViewProgressButtonBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.view_progress_button, null, false);
```

instead of:

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_progress_button, this, true)
```

Using the `binding` object, you can do:

```
binding.setViewModel(yourViewModelInstance)
```

You can instantiate your ViewModel however, but inside your ViewModel class you should have `onProgressButtonClick()` defined.

If I remember correctly, you might need to do something like this in your layout for the `onClick`:

```
android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onProgressButtonClick()}"
```

because the lambda expects the view as a parameter.

Another note is that you no longer need to do `findViewById` since you have access to that view like so:

```
binding.button
```

Comment: This shouldn't really be an accepted answer. The whole idea of a custom component is so that its reusable. In this case its not re-usable at all, you may as well just move the FrameLayout to the one spot you can use it rather than this round-about databinding to a specific viewmodel.